# Change jstree node text colour based on type

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I have been searching the interent for an age and couldnt find an answer. I was trying to change node text colour dependant on the type of the particular node. So in this example i wanted to change the text colour of every node that is a "Role" type defined in data.

```
    $("#roleTree").jstree({
        json_data: {
            data: roleTreeData
        },
        "themes": {
            "theme": "default",
            "dots": true,
            "icons": false
        },
        "ui": {
            "select_limit": 1,
            "select_multiple_modifier": "none"
        },
        "types": {
            "types": {
                "AM": {
                    "hover_node": false,
                    "select_node": false
                },
                "AF": {
                    "hover_node": false,
                    "select_node": false
                },
                "Role": {
// i dont know if possible to be done here? add class?
             //   this.css("color", "red")
                    //{ font-weight:bold}
                }
            }
        },

        plugins: ["themes", "json_data", "ui", "Select", "types", "crrm"]

    }).bind("loaded.jstree", function (event, data)
    {
        $("#roleTree").jstree("open_all");
         data.inst.select_node('ul > li:first');

    }).bind("select_node.jstree", function (event, data)
    {
        selectedRoleId = data.rslt.obj.attr("id");
        window.selectedRole = GetRole(selectedRoleId);              
    });
}
```

Or any other method to highlight or tell users that only the role is selectable.

Comment: Theorically "Role" is stored in the attribute "rel" of the li tag (or the a tag), so you can manualy change the css in your stylesheet :
"li[rel="Role"] { background-color: #ff0000; }". Then with your css you can also handle the events (hover, focus, ...).

Comment: Ricola3D, your suggestion doesn't seem to work - it changes the background colour of the whole tree. I wanted to change the node text colour only for the "Role" type node.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done using the following CSS, assuming you are using the default classic theme.

```
.jstree-classic li[rel="Role"] > a { color:red; }
```

Get `jstree-classic` class, where child `li` has `rel` attribute of `Role`, get the first child `a` of that `li` and assign color to red.

Comment: True, it's the <a> tag you've to color.